# easy direct limit and inverse limit

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am a very beginner in algebra. I want to ask some very simple questions

what are these direct limit and inverse limit of groups:

1) $\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z^2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z^3} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z^4} \longrightarrow\mathbb{Z^5}\longrightarrow\cdots$ where the maps are inclusions in the first coordinates.

2) $\mathbb{Z}\longleftarrow \mathbb{Z^2} \longleftarrow  \mathbb{Z^3}  \longleftarrow  \mathbb{Z^4} \longleftarrow $$\mathbb{Z^5}\longleftarrow \cdots $ where the maps are projections in the first coordinates.

Comment: The first is the direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ and the second is the direct product.

Answer (score 1):

The answers have already been given in a comment above.

(1) More generally, in a nice concrete category (groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, posets), any direct limit of linearly ordered subobjects of a given one will be the *union* of those subobjects.

We can identify $\Bbb Z^n$ as a subgroup of $\Bbb Z^{\oplus\Bbb N}$ (elements with all coordinates beyond $n$ zero), and the inclusions make them linearly ordered for $n=1,2,\cdots$. The union of these subgroups is the whole space - can you verify this? Show every element of $\Bbb Z^{\oplus\Bbb N}$ is in $\Bbb Z^n$ for some $n$.

(2) Given that the inverse limit is the direct product of countably-many copies of $\Bbb Z$, can you figure out what the projection maps $\to\Bbb Z^n$ for $n=1,2,\cdots$ are? Can you prove that this inverse limit satisfies the correct universal property that it's supposed to?